# MKMapView and CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I want to use a MKMapView to display the user current location using the default breathing blue pin and I want to record the user movement at the same time. Is there any way that I could use the GPS manager (not sure if this is a CLLocationManager) the MKMapView uses when we enabled it to show user location?

I know that I can create my own CLLocationManager. But this feels like adding an overhead to my application and I would like the map and my tracking to remain in sync.

I already explored the following ideas without success:

- Use the `[MKMapView showUserLocation:YES]` and add KVO on the `userLocation` field. This does not work and I am wondering if this is due to the fact that the `userLocation` field is read only.
- Use the `[MKMapView showUserLocation:YES]`, create a `MKMapViewDelegate` and add the tracking when the annotation view for the user location is requested. This does not work, because the annotation view is apparently requested only once???
- Use a `CLLocationManager` and try to add the blue pin manually. Unfortunately, I did not find the blue pin in the available pin types, so I tried to create a user annotation manually without success.

Does anyone has any idea how I can achieve this and still benefit from the blue pin or is my only solution to use a `CLLocationManager` and create my own pin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`CLLocationManager` uses the same data across all of its instances. `MKMapView` uses `CLLocationManager's` data internally. That said the solution to do what you want to do is let `MKMapView` do its own thing with regards to `showUserLocation:`. At the same time, create an instance of `CLLocationManager` and its delegate.

The delegate messages will give you the GPS coordinate location of `MKMapView's` blue pin. Everything will be in sync with each other.

Comment: Thanks Giao. I guess that "CLLocationManager uses the same data across all of its instances" is what I needed to hear ;)

Comment: Are you sure that CLLocationManager uses the same data across all of its instances?  If that was the case, wouldn't Apple have made it a singleton like UIApplication?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5930620/1055722 (near the bottom of it) indicates that CLLocationManager does *not* share the same data across all instances. Do you happen to have a reference you can cite?

Comment: Cool, that was an answer from a question I posted when I first started with maps stuffs. Looks like things haven't changed much since :) I guess if you use map view, then it might be better if you just stick with it and not use CLLocationManager on top of it. I suppose the values are not too different?

Comment: In my app, I finally used the MKMapView to display the user location, and CLLocationManager to record the locations. I have noticed that the locations differs a little bit between MKMapView and CLLocationManager.

Comment: The `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol has a function: `mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!)`. How does this differ from using a `CLLocationManager`?

Comment: Why there are slight differences between those 2 results like map view and location manager