# How to set accuracy and distance filter when using MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

When i use `setShowsUserLocation` with `MKMapView` to track user location, how do I set the accuracy and distance filter? I am not talking about `CLLocationManager`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can't control the accuracy of the internal `MKMapView` location manager (the one used to track the user with the blue dot), but you can create your own and use it to recenter the map. Here is a recipe...

### To handle core location permissions

In the Core Location Delegate:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
        NSLog(@"User has denied location services");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Location manager did fail with error: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
    }
}
```

Right before setting up the location manager:

```
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
    NSLog(@"location services are disabled"];
    return;
}
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
    NSLog(@"location services are blocked by the user");
    return;
}
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){
    NSLog(@"location services are enabled");
}  
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
    NSLog(@"about to show a dialog requesting permission");
}
```

### To setup core location

```
self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
self.locationManager.purpose = @"Tracking your movements on the map.";
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

/* Pinpoint our location with the following accuracy:
 *
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation  highest + sensor data
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyBest               highest     
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters   10 meters   
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters      100 meters
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer          1000 meters 
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers    3000 meters
 */
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

/* Notify changes when device has moved x meters.
 * Default value is kCLDistanceFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;

/* Notify heading changes when heading is > 5.
 * Default value is kCLHeadingFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.headingFilter = 5;

// update location
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

### To recenter the map with our location manager

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f } };
    region.center = newLocation.coordinate;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.15f; 
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.15f;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Put that on the delegate. MKMapView doesn't have a distance or accuracy filter, only the CLLocationManager does. What MKMapView has is a region span around a point, in the example above 0.15 degrees (0.15*111 Km).

### Things that I tried and didn't work

The documentation doesn't tell where `MKMapView` is getting its updates from. I tried

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"newLocation %@", newLocation.timestamp);
    NSLog(@"last map location %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[self.mapView userLocation] location] timestamp]]);
}
```

and I'm getting different values on each. It looks as if `MKMapView` uses its own `CLLocationManager`, which means you can't set its accuracy. You can't add your delegate for the `CLLocationManager` of the `MKMapView` either.

My impression is that the only way to set the accuracy is setting show user position to NO and create a custom annotation with a blue dot, which means recentering the map manually as posted. You can get the blue dot graphic from the SDK with the github project artwork-extractor.

I don't know if I'm missing something or this part of `MKMapView` just sucks.

Comment: The code you provided is for CLLocationManager not MKMapView.

Comment: Hi Jano, in this case, if I use also [MKMapView setShowsUserLocation] then won't I be having two location requests process running in parallel? One from MKMapView and one from CLLocation Manager? Thanks again for clarifying.

Comment: I guess you will. If you want custom accuracy I would use a custom annotation and set it to NO. Looks like a workaround, but I don't know better. I'll upvote the question and hope for another opinion.

Comment: @VanDuTran Avoid using manually posted custom annotations. It will eat up CPU speed if the devices is traveling fast. Better approach is to add UIImageView wrapped around the 'a blue dot', as a subview of MKMapViews view -- that will use the GPU to render the annotation Will work as long as its not possible to scroll the map.

Answer (score 3):

For displaying map here is an example code.

First import MKMapKit and CoreLocation framework in your .h file.

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
 #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Add MKMapKit and CoreLocation Delegate in .h file

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>


CGPoint gameMapCenter = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height / 2);
    gameMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 620)];
    [gameMapView setCenter:gameMapCenter];
    [gameMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [gameMapView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:gameMapView];
    [gameMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

Use `CLLocationManager` for fetching user location.

Declare an instance of CLLocationManager

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

In `ViewDidLoad`

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

[locationManager setDelegate:self];

[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

[locationManger startUpdatingLocation];
```

`startUpdatingLocation` Method Implementation:

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
      //Your Stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes but I need to display a map.. the map is the main view of my application.

Comment: @VanDuTran hey i update my answer here you can find how to add mapview   and how to fetch userlocation.

Comment: Because of this [gameMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES]; and [locationManger startUpdatingLocation];, you will have double notifications?

Comment: @VanDuTran no, you won't, the map own CLLocationManager is separated from your CLLocationManager

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the accuracy, however, you can get the accuracy via the userLocation in the MKMapView delegate method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%f", userLocation.location.horizontalAccuracy);
}
```