# Does the accuracy property influence the accuracy of mapview.userLocation? [Titanium]

Tags: geolocation, gps, maps, titanium

I'm using the mapview property userLocation to show the users location on a map. Does it matter what value Ti.Geolocation.accuracy has or is the accuracy of the position marker (as it is a part of the map app) only influenced by the map app?

If it's latter: On Android I (as a User) can choose only between wifi/gps accuracy. Is the accuracy controlled automaticly (e.g. according to the battary charge)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that accuracy settings only apply to the Geolocation module. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930612/how-to-set-accuracy-and-distance-filter-when-using-mkmapview), these settings have no effect on the user location accuracy on map views.

Comment: Didn't find this thread since I was looking for "Titanium stuff". But this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accuracy you choose, iOS uses its own logic to select location providers and filter location updates to provide location updates that meet your accuracy requirements.

Also remember: Location services stay enabled for as long as a listener is registered for the location event, so be sure to remove the event listener when you do not require location updates.

You can read more about it in [Titanium.Geolocation documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation).

Rule of thumb is not overusing accuracy level when you are accessing user location. Be nice for your users and their devices. If your app will drain their battery in minutes they will remove your app and never come back to it.