# Setting CoreLocation Distance Filter?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am new to using Swift and I want to use the Core Location framework. I want to set my distance filter so that whenever my phone detects a 10 meter distance change, an update event is generated. The following is what I tried to make it work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0;
}
```

I tried to look at [How to set accuracy and distance filter when using MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930612/how-to-set-accuracy-and-distance-filter-when-using-mkmapview) for reference as how to use the distanceFilter function to set it to send an update every 10 meters but every time I run my iPhone simulator, the simulator crashes at that line. If I set it to `10.0f`, I get an error saying `Consequtive statements must be separated by ';'` Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to set distance filter to 10 Metres is:

```
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
```

You don't need a semicolon.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for your help! Sorry this is a bit off topic, but I'm trying to set the distances of the regions I have created in the Core Location. Would you happen to know how to do something like this? I tried to set the distance filter to 10 but that set the radius of each region to 10 meters.

Comment: Sure! - it's really quite simple... So you need to create CLCircularRegion objects and instantiate them with a location and a radius. Then you can build up an array of 'regions' and tell your locationManager to monitor them. Does this make sense?