# iOS: Difference between the location I get from CLLocationManager and MKMapView's userLocation property

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have two view controllers: `tweetViewController` and `MapViewController`. The former is for user to post a tweet, and in it I use `CLLocationManager` to get user's location. Once `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is called, I got "locationA", I'll remind user that his location has been set.

User can just post the tweet with "locationA". Or change the location manually (in case the location is not accurate enough) by clicking the location info. In this case, `MapViewController` is pushed, and there is an draggable pin annotation associated with locationA fall down to the map. I found the pin is hundreds of meters apart from where I am. Then, I set `mapView.showUserLocation = YES`. And I found the blue bubble's location is much more accurate than the pin. So, my question is how can I get mapView's `userLocation` in the `tweetViewController` rather than the location from `CLLocationManager`.

I'm in China, I've been searching for the same problem. Some people say map in China is transformed, so then there must be an offset. Any suggestion to deal with the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you correctly set your location manager accuracy and distance filter settings? normally the defaults give the best accuracy. And are you also correctly updating the location based on the delegate events? consider intact that when you start updating location using CLLocationManager it may happen that the first returned location is highly inaccurate due to successive approximations (cellular signal first, GPS signal later) or because it just got the last known location (it could be hours or days old): always check the "newLocation" timestamp and compare it with current date.

Comment: I set desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest and distanceFilter = 5.0f, which I think is accurate enough. I can get the delegate method called several times, as in five times and then the location is stable. no more call of the delegate. Then I push the mapViewController. But still, the locationManager's location is hundreds of meters apart from the mapView's userLocation... Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

**Finally**, 
I use a `MKMapView` instance to solve this problem.

Setting

`mapView.showUserLocation = YES/NO; //to start/stop locating.`

Using

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

to get the user location. In my controller, `mapView` is not shown, it's only used to get user location and the location is more accurate than which i get from `locManager`.

Answer (score -1):

`CLLocationManager` uses the same data across all of its instances. `MKMapView` uses `CLLocationManager`'s data internally. That said the solution to do what you want to do is let `MKMapView` do its own thing with regards to `showUserLocation:`. At the same time, create an instance of `CLLocationManager` and its delegate.

The delegate messages will give you the GPS coordinate location of `MKMapView`'s blue pin. Everything will be in sync with each other.

Comment: Hi Vinay, thanks for your answer. I still have a question, in my case, there will be no mapViewController if user doesn't click "change location" button. Also, I wonder why the two coordinates is different if using the same CLLocationManager's data? Is it said MKMapView do some adjustment for the coordinate?

Comment: Would be nice if you referred your answer. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2319673/3826773